# Accessing OnPremises Active Directory from WebRole running in Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-connect

I am trying to access the onpremises active directory from the web application running on Azure. We have selected Azure Connect as it best fits our requirement (authenticate user as well as fetch user information from Active Directory).

I have followed the steps provided in this [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432997.aspx) and [link2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_connect_team_blog/archive/2010/12/10/domain-joining-windows-azure-roles.aspx), but still failing to achieve the goal.

Below is the method, I a trying to test if the onpremises Active Directory is reachable from Azure: `DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP Path")`

Below is the error I am encountering:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007054B): The
>   specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Exists(String path)    at
>   WebRole1.MyLogInPage.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

I can see the connect endpoint software is running fine without any connectivity issue, on the server running Active Directory and the endpoint group is properly setup.

Comment: Have you ensured that the machines can actually see each other?  I've seen in the past where the Endpoint software says things are all fine, but the machines still can actually talk to each other.  Have you tried ensuring you can ping the Azure box from the AD Server or vice versa?